# How create log file using Log4j for jsp page

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, tomcat8

I want to create log file using Log4j. I want to create such logs.

**"2018-10-31 21:05:51,481 - DEBUG - u click button"**

I downloaded `log4j-2.3-bin`.

Added files `log4j-api-2.3.jar` and `log4j-api-2.3.jar`, clicked "build path" and create `log4j.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration status="DEBUG">
   <Appenders>
     <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
     </Console>
     <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
       <.PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </File>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
     <Root level="debug">
       <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
       <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
     </Root>
   </Loggers>
 </Configuration>
```

**I am confused and do not quite understand how to finish.**

I'm using IDE eclipse for web-development with tomcat 8.5.

**MyFile.jps**

```
<form  method="POST">
    <input  type="submit" name="Clickme" value ="buttonclick" >
        <%
            String button1Click = request.getParameter("buttonclick");
            if(button1Click != null && button1Click.equals("buttonclick")){
        %>
            <p> click </p>
        <%  
            }
        %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dummy class, you need it to instantiate the logger:

```
public class JspLoggerClass {}
```

Import the logger and the class in your jsp:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger, JspLoggerClass;" %>
```

Instantiate and use:

```
  <%
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JspLoggerClass.class);
    ...
    logger.info("message ...");
  %>
```

**EDITED**

I don't understand you very well. Using log4j you can write only from java code. That for in jsp you use the logger in scriptlet only. If you want to log the click event, that is javascript, so the only logger is **console.log("...")** but this prints on the browser console.
When you click the button, there is no way to get the event in jsp scriptlet, this code is executed on the server. What you can do is submit the form, go to a servlet on your server and **there** log the event.

**EDITED 2**

OK, my fault, you are using 2.3 and that is *log4j 2*.
So include in your project / classpath *log4j-core* and *log4j-api* jars. Import *org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager* and *org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger*. No need to create dummy class, you could instantiate the logger with a string name like this:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("my jsp");
```

And now just use the logger:

```
logger.info("...");
```

Sorry, I cannot post comments.

I think you have an error in your *log4j.xml*, remove the **dot** before *PatternLayout*.

Comment: what version is it written for? I have version 2.3 and what you wrote is not working

Comment: Now error Invalid directive. How correct import log4j-api-2.3.jar? Do you have normal instruction? Please

Comment: in my file i don't have a dot.

Comment: On the line 8 in the file you've posted there is a dot. I don0t know how you can import log4j-api-2.3.jar. You must have a server, e.g. Tomcat, so just put the jar in your server/lib folder. If you deploy a war, make sure you have the jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Change **fileName="all.log"** to something like **/home/myUser/logs/all.log** or just a path you know.

Comment: Don't log INFO level, you have configured DEBUG. Change logger.info to logger.debug or change your settings to `status="ALL"` or something less restrictive. Also you should change the File section to `append="true"` and `immediateFlush="true"`

Comment: Nothing has happened. Okay. Thanks for the help